# Can you have an IIF nested within IIF in a Control Source?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003, iif

Is this valid in MS Access VBA:

```
iif ([company] = "starbucks", "retail", iif ([item] <> "", "DLookup(....)", ""))
```

I'm trying to get something similar to the above work.

Comment: Nested IIfs can be a warning sign that there is an easier solution.

Comment: @Remou: Good point.  @Bruno: Consider the `Switch` function for moderately more complex scenarios or a query-based approach if you find yourself including multiple `DLookup`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can nest up to 14 `IIf` statements before Jet/ACE complains that the "Expression is too complex."  There is no similar limitation on the VBA `IIf` function.

Since you are using this in the Control Source of the form, Access will evaluate this using its Expression Service (which essentially treats it as though it were part of a Jet/ACE query) so the 14 levels of nesting limit will apply.

Note also that I referred to the Jet/ACE `IIf` as a *statement* and the VBA `IIf` as a *function*.  While those terms are sometimes used loosely, they have precise meaning.  The `IIf` statement of Jet/ACE is a true [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator).  The upshot is that it is generally more efficient than the VBA function of the same name and it does not suffer from potential [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf#Side_Effects).